# Как прописать пространство имён для Actions?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Используется: C#, WebDriver, Chrome, VisualStudio 2015

Visual Studio выдаёт ошибку:

> The type or namespace name 'Actions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Код:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(browser1);
var element = browser1.FindElement(By.Id("element-id"));

actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

**Вопрос:** Как прописать пространство Actions или избавится от ошибки?

Comment: подключить библиотеку к проекту. using используй

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте ссылку на сборку WebDriver.dll и используйте using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions; написано [тут](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions_MoveToElement.htm)